# Setting a JSF list box directly from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'd like to directly set the listbox elements defined in a jsf block via setting them in a javascript code, but the document.getElementById() returns null ?

JSF Code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="dtEffectiveDate">
                                <h:outputText value="EffectiveDates:" style="margin-left: 250px;width:76px;"/>
                                    <h:selectManyListbox id="effectiveDateListbox" style="margin-left: 15px; width:76px;" size="2">
                                        <c:selectItems id="effectiveDateSelectItems" value="#{manualDataEntryRegText.effectiveDates}"/>
                                    </h:selectManyListbox>
                                </h:panelGroup>
```

JavaScript code:

```
CalendarPopup.handleSelectForMultipleDates = function(type, args, obj, inputEl)
    {
    alert("MultiSelect");
    var arrDates = CalendarPopup.effectiveDateCalendar.getSelectedDates();
    var length = arrDates.length;
    var i=0;
    var tokenizedDates = "";

    var txtDate = document.getElementById("pageForm:effectiveDateListbox");
    alert(txtDate); // returns null
    for (i = 0; i!= length; i++) 
    {
        var date = arrDates[i];
        var displayMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var displayYear = date.getFullYear();
        var displayDate = date.getDate();
        tokenizedDates = displayMonth.toString(10) + "/" + displayDate.toString(10) + "/" + displayYear.toString(10);
        effectiveDateListbox.options[i].value = tokenizedDates;
        i++;
    } 


    }
```

EDIT: I am able to get the listbox but cannot set it:
How do I set the listbox ?

```
var listBox = document.getElementById('pageForm:effectiveDateListbox');
        for (i = 0; i!= length; i++) 
        {
            var date = arrDates[i];
            var displayMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var displayYear = date.getFullYear();
            var displayDate = date.getDate();
            tokenizedDates = displayMonth.toString(10) + "/" + displayDate.toString(10) + "/" + displayYear.toString(10);
            listBox.options[i].value = tokenizedDates;
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Is that the `id` of the element when you view the HTML source rendered by JSF?

Comment: This is what i see  <span id="pageForm:dtEffectiveDate"/>

Comment: This is what i see now: <select id="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" name="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" multiple="multiple" size="0"></select>

Answer (score 0):

This should not return `null`:

```
<select id="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" name="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" multiple="multiple" size="0"></select>

document.getElementById('pageForm:effectiveDateListbox');
```

If it is, it might be that the `select` element does not exist at the time your javascript is running. To protect against that you could try:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // do stuff here
};
```